# UIWebView from UITableview from TabBarController not loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiwebview

Trying to load a url being passed from the previous viewcontroller in a tabviewcontroller sequence. Checked the usual suspects. UIWebview is added view outlet. All the proper delegate are connected. I'm not sure if the NSURL is being passed to the next view controller as I get a black screen (although the response object isn't nil). It's driving me crazy because it's a simple problem and it's something I've done millions of times but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Below you'll find the code.

SquirrelInformationTableViewController.m

```
@interface ASAInformationTabViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *squirrelArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) ODRefreshControl *refreshControl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *squirrelListTableView;

@end

@implementation ASAInformationTabViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self setUpSquirrelList];
    //Add drag to refresh function
    self.refreshControl = [[ODRefreshControl alloc]initInScrollView:self.squirrelListTableView];
    self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:46.0/255 green:172.0/255 blue:247.0/255 alpha:1];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(dragToRefreshAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}



-(void)setUpSquirrelList
{

    __weak UITableView* weaktable = self.squirrelListTableView;
    [[ASASquirrelManager instance] listSquirrels:^(NSString *response, NSMutableArray *result) {


        if ([response isEqualToString:CODE_SUCCESS]) {
            squirrelArray = result;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (weaktable) {
                    [weaktable reloadData];
                }
            });
    }

    }];
}



-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        ASASquirrelInformationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"squirrelIdentifier"];
        ASASquirrelModel *squirrelLocal = squirrelArray[indexPath.row];
        cell.squirrelTitleLabel.text = squirrelLocal.title;
        cell.squirrelDescLabel.text = squirrelLocal.desc;

        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:squirrelLocal.image]];
        cell.squirrelImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


        return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ASASquirrelModel *squirrelWebLocal = squirrelArray[indexPath.row];

    NSString *squirrelURLString = squirrelWebLocal.url;
    //create an array with the string you want an access it
    NSLog(@"%@", urlStringArray);

    //Create a string from the URL pass it to the sdvc.string

    SquirrelDetailViewController *sdvc = [SquirrelDetailViewController new];
    sdvc.urlString = squirrelURLString;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sdvc animated:YES];

}
```

SquirrelDetailViewController.m

```
@interface SquirrelDetailViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate> 

@end

@implementation SquirrelDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    self.urlstr = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.urlstr];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: Be wary of adding anything to the view in `viewDidLoad` that needs information about the view's size, as this information is not accurate here.

Comment: Indeed. I realized that too and removed the viewdDidLoad size specs.

Comment: Where is self.webView created? You said it was an outlet so why do you need to add it as a subview? Should it not already be in the view hierarchy from storyboard or wherever you created the design?

Comment: Yes, I realize this mistake and remove the self.webview addsubview. It's already connected as an outlet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create the instance of the `sdvc` using storyboard otherwise it will not be getting instantiated properly. So:

```
SquirrelDetailViewController *sdvc = 
  (SquirrelDetailViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"XXX" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YYY"];
```

where XXX is your storyboard name and YYY is the storyboard identifier for SquirrelDetailViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the trouble was I wasn't preparing for segue. (hits forehead*)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"webviewpush" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"webviewpush"]) {

        // Get destination view
        SquirrelDetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *path = [self.squirrelListTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        ASASquirrelModel *squirrelWebLocal = squirrelArray[path.row];
        NSString *squirrelURLString = squirrelWebLocal.url;
        vc.urlString = squirrelURLString;

    }
}
```

If you'll excuse me I'm going to go drown myself now.